# How to get_dummies in testing

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm doing get_dummies in machine learning model and test only using one unit analysis, previously I develop in pandas dataframe for training and testing, and create a model that requires all column in my expected output

Here's just one example my input

```
gender     file_type          image_size_category   prefix_category
MALE             jpg                     p200x200               jpg
```

the output I want is

```
gender_FEMALE  gender_MALE  gender_NEUTER  gender_UNKNOWN  file_type_jpg  file_type_png image_size_category_p200x200  image_size_category_p240x240  image_size_category_s200x200 prefix_category_a  prefix_category_jpg  prefix_category_png

            0            1              0               0              1              0                            1                             0                             0                0                     1             0
```

Comment: There is no way to get the missing columns without providing them. How else should the program "know" that you expect FEMALE/NEUTER/UNKNOWN or png? Otherwise a simple: `pd.get_dummies(df, dtype=int)`